# JS Canvas Drawing only works sometimes?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, filereader

I want to create a Whiteboard application on which the User can draw (I'm using an HTML `<canvas>`). I just completed coding a function that imports an PNG image and draws it onto the Canvas:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('can');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
        
function drawImageOntoCanvas (e) {
        var input = e.target;
        var img = new Image();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
            var dataURL = reader.result;
            img.src = dataURL;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
```

```html
<input id="uploadFromPC" type="file" accept='image/png' onchange="drawImageOntoCanvas(event);"></input>
<canvas id="can" width="1000px" height="500px" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;"></canvas>
```

This works, but only sometimes for some reason. It doesn't work at first, then, when I reload the page, it works again. Then, it doesn't work, but it does after reloading and so on.

I tried logging the Data URL in the console, as well as the result of the reader. Both work perfectly fine.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I'm not very familiar with JS, so it could be that I'm missing something here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your script placed in the html file? is it inside the head tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, depending on timing, you might be drawing the image before it has finished loading.

You can address that as follows, even though I would suggest using a little more modern JavaScript (`addEventListener()`, `const`, `let`, promises, etc.):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('can');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;

function drawImageOntoCanvas(e) {
  var input = e.target;
  var img = new Image();
  
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    img.src = reader.result;
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
    }
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<input id="uploadFromPC" type="file" accept='image/png' onchange="drawImageOntoCanvas(event);"></input>
<canvas id="can" width="1000px" height="500px" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;"></canvas>
```